# Would a black hole-white hole pair self-propagate?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, white-holes

Would a black hole-white hole pair of equal size self propagate in the direction of the black hole? Suppose the pair are initially stationary relative to each other, with the white hole on the x axis just to the left of the origin and the black hole just to the right, with the setup symmetric up to a reflection across the y axis (or x=0 plane) switching the sign on the time coordinate. A massive test particle placed an epsilon to the right of the black hole on the x axis would fall toward the black hole leftwards, as the influence of the white hole would be insignificant for epsilon sufficiently small. Arguably, a test particle placed anywhere on the x axis to the right of the black hole would fall leftwards, because the gravitational pull of the black hole would outweigh the impact of the white hole, which is further away. By symmetry, a test particle placed anywhere to the left of the white hole would fall leftwards. Thus, in the frame of reference of a test particle anywhere to the right (left), the pair would be approaching (receding). So is the pair self propagating to the right? Note: I have not found any relevant literature; there is a stack exchange question about a colliding pairs but mine is about an initially stationary pair.

Comment: If the black hole and white hole are far enough away from each other, then you can use the nonrelativistic + weak-field approximation, in which general relativity agrees with Newton's model of gravity. Then the question becomes whether a positive-mass and negative-mass pair would self propagate. Do you already know the answer in that approximation?

Comment: A white hole has positive mass just like a black hole.

Answer (score 2):

OP is mixing the concepts of *white hole* and *negative mass*. White hole is simply the time reversed black hole, time reversal does not change the mass sign, so a pair white hole/black hole would *not* self accelerate, would attract each other, and if initial conditions allow, merge forming a bigger black hole (not a white hole). This merger would then be an illustration of white hole instability: white holes tend to turn black.

On the other hand, a pair of bodies with opposite signs of mass indeed can self-accelerate. A body with positive mass could be a black hole (or a white hole), but a body with negative mass would be either a naked singularity or might contain exotic matter. Solution of Einstein field equations for such a self-accelerating pair has been constructed first by H. Bondi:

- Bondi, Hermann. *Negative mass in general relativity*. Reviews of Modern Physics 29.3 (1957): 423, [doi:10.1103/RevModPhys.29.423](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.29.423), [free pdf](http://ayuba.fr/pdf/bondi1957.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. With a constant acceleration, the negative mass-positive mass pair will approach the speed of light. In some sense, the pair has zero mass. A zero-mass self propagating element with velocity approaching the speed of light sounds like a photon, yes?
This 1951 [note]{https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5852e579be659442a01f27b8/t/5873dc04d1758eea4b41c720/1483987972731/luttinger.pdf} demonstrates the self propagation.